# Prime OS 2.1.3 VGA error. Screen ghosting. How to fix it?

Tags: android

**After booting Prime OS 2.1.3, the Prime OS loading screen is shaded like this. I tried it on other computers and it works. That's what happens on this computer. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me.**

Notebook Specs:

[Dell Inspiron 3580 Full Specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/inspiron-15-3580-laptop/inspiron-3580-2sp-setup-and-specifications/specifications-of-inspiron-3580?guid=guid-7c9f07ce-626e-44ca-be3a-a1fb036413f9&lang=en-us)

Notebook: Dell Inspiron 3580

CPU: Intel© Core™ i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4

GPU1: AMD Radeon 520 2GB GDDR5

GPU2: Intel UHD Graphics 620

Ram: 8GB

Screen: 1920x1080

[Prime OS Error Screen Shading Video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3HAgxhsNqI)

[image: Prime Os Grub menu]

[image: Prime OS Grub menu edit mode]

[image: Prime OS loading boot]

Comment: The system requirements of Prime OS mention you need a `VIDEO CARD: NVIDIA GeForce – 128 MB VRAM` (or better). May be thy only support nVidia cards?

Comment: Thank you for your attention and response, sir. Prime OS versions 0.6.1 and older work normally. I only get a screenshot like this in the latest version. Can I add any ALTERNATIVE VGA code lines in the grub menu? is there a code like this?